# Combining two lists with C#

Tags: c#

In OCaml, there's a function which takes two lists of the same size and returns a list of tuples:

```
val combine : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list
```

Is there something similar in C#?

I don't I have strong requirements about the output's type. It can be a list of tuples, or something like a dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method. The second argument tells the method what to do with each pair of elements.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = a.Zip(b, Tuple.Create);

IEnumerable<int> sums = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x + y);
```

If one collection is larger than the other, the remaining elements of the larger collection will be ignored.